# Why is my Percentage 0 when run on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I'm building following Oracle SQL query.I try to gain the salesmen who sold the most international payments between 2 dates.

I have following query

```
SELECT ddo.CODE as "Salesman ID", ROUND((count(fpp.ID) / 
    (SELECT count(fpp2.ID) 
    FROM Payments_Table fpp2
        JOIN Clients_Table da2 ON fpp2.Client_ID = da2.ID
        JOIN Currency_Table dc2 ON dc2.ID = fpp2.CURRENCY_ID
     WHERE dc2.CURRENCY_CODE != da2.CURRENCY
    ) * 100), 2) AS "% Different currency"
FROM Salesmen_Table ddo
    JOIN Payments_Table fpp ON ddo.ID = fpp.DATA_OWNER_ID
    JOIN Clients_Table da ON fpp.ORDERING_ACCOUNT_ID = da.ID
    JOIN Currency_Table dc ON fpp.CURRENCY_ID = dc.ID
WHERE da.CURRENCY != dc.CURRENCY_CODE
GROUP BY ddo.CODE
```

Which should give a descending list, based on percentage of the number of international payments. Like the following:

> - Salesman ID           % Different currency
> - Jack                  66.66
> - John                  33.33

I have 3 payments in my database, 2 for Jack and 1 for John, so this is the result which I expect. But the result of my % is 0. How does this come?

Comment: You could consider using ratio_to_report analytic function.

Comment: Add the two counts as separate fields to ensure that the divisor isn't so big that the percentage is less than 0.01%

Comment: the expected percentages are 33.33 and 66.66 so I don't think this solves the problem.

Comment: Are you asking why the statement works on Oracle but not on SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The difference is caused because Oracle's `INTEGER` is essentially an alias for NUMBER(38,0). There is a related SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494010/difference-between-number-and-integer-datatype-in-oracle-dictionary-views). Dividing two integers actually performs decimal division, so 1/2 will return 0.5

SQL Server on the other hand has several integer types (smallint, tinyint, int, ) and dividing integers performs an integer division. 1/2 will return 0

**ORIGINAL**

You are dividing integers. In integer division, the result is an integer itself. This means that percentage values less than 100% (ie 1) become 0.

You should convert at least one operand to a float/decimal before the division. This is as simple as multiplying the *dividend* by `100.0`, eg:

```
ROUND( (100.0*count(fpp.ID)) / ...
```

Comment: This is not correct - [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/529a2/1/0) gives an example of a table with two integer columns (`NUMBER(1,0)`) and the result of the division is a decimal.

Comment: @MT0 I replied while the question was still tagged `sql-server`.

Comment: @Guil *what* are you trying to do? Run the same query on both databases? In SQL Server integer division returns an integer. As MT0 noted oracle returns a decimal and the original query should work

Comment: So you are saying that my query is incompatible with SQL Server?

Comment: If you are trying to use the same query in both databases, it isn't *incompatible*, it's just that integer division works differently  - or rather, Oracle doesn't have *integers* and integer division, it has `NUMBER` with 0 scale.