# Difference between Number and Integer in SQL Datatypes?

Tags: sql

i want to know the basic difference between sql datatype Number and Integer.

Comment: There is no data type `number` in standard SQL - which DBMS are you using? And what does the manual for that DBMS say about those data types?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494010/difference-between-number-and-integer-datatype-in-oracle-dictionary-views

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494010/difference-between-number-and-integer-datatype-in-oracle-dictionary-views

Answer (score 0):

Number allows a decimal component (Ex: 3.43)
Integer doesn't.  If you try to store 3.43 in an Integer, it will just store 3

Number allows for much larger values than Integer does.

If you are using whole numbers, I recommend using Integer.  If you are using numbers that may have a decimal component, I recommend Number.

Comment: Which dbms are you talking about? (Number must be a product specific data type.)