# how to define check constraint in oracle

Tags: oracle, constraints

In below code how to define check constraint which can prevent values 10,20,30 from inserting

```
create table testtable(
  testtableid integer primary key, 
  testtableno integer unique,
  testtablename varchar2(255),
  testtablevalue number check(testtablevalue <>10 
                            or testtablevalue <>20
                            or  testtablevalue<>30),
  testtable date DEFAULT sysdate, 
  empid number FOREIGN key  references empmaster(empid)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

`INTEGER` is one of the ANSI data types that Oracle supports and notes its equivalent is `NUMBER(p,0)`. Using INTEGER has semantic value in that reviewers will know that it is not just a number of a set precision but it is required to be an integer.

(Check this answer to better understand the difference between INTEGER and NUMBER in Oracle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23916374/2611451)

You need the `CONSTRAINT` keyword and you can use `NOT IN` in order to define the check constraint:

```
create table testtable(
   testtableid Number primary key, 
   testtableno Number unique,
   testtablename varchar2(255),
   testtablevalue Number,
   ...
   CONSTRAINT tblValue_chk check(testtablevalue NOT IN (10, 20, 30))
   ....
)
```

**EDIT**

The check can also be applied inline:

```
create table testtable(
    testtableid Number primary key, 
    testtableno Number unique,
    testtablename varchar2(255),
    testtablevalue Number check(testtablevalue NOT IN (10, 20, 30))
)
```

Comment: The `constraint` keyword is required for table level constraints; it is perfectly valid to define check constraints inline.

Comment: [Oracle 12c Data Types Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00213) includes `INTEGER` as one of the ANSI data types that Oracle supports and notes its equivalent is `NUMBER(p,0)` but makes zero reference to it being deprecated. Do you have a reference for your statement that it is? Using `INTEGER` has semantic value in that reviewers will know that it is not just a number of a set precision but it is required to be an integer.

Comment: I bet this is just some falsified information used in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494010/difference-between-number-and-integer-datatype-in-oracle-dictionary-views. I don't think it is deprecated as well, I edited the answer

Answer (score 3):

> "prevent values 10,20,30"

You want to prevent all those values so you need to use Boolean AND.

```
testtablevalue number check(testtablevalue <> 10 
                            AND testtablevalue <> 20 
                            AND  testtablevalue<>30),
```

Using NOT IN requires less typing for longer lists of proscribed values: